# Selecting distinct values from one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I retrieve only unique values from a column using PHP and MYSQL?

Here's the content of table1:

```
id     value       
_____________________
1      Max Power
2      Homer Simpson
3      Max Power
4      Lisa Simpson
5      Lisa Simpson
```

So, obviously, I want these results:

```
- Max Power
- Homer Simpson
- Lisa Simpson
```

but I'm still getting:

```
- Max Power
- Homer Simpson
- Max Power
- Lisa Simpson
- Lisa Simpson
```

The SQL statements that I've tried are below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM column1
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM column1 GROUP BY value
```

Obviously these should work. So here's my full SQL statement just in case there's something fishy there:

```
    <?php
$dblink = mysql_connect(‘host’, ‘username’, ‘password’) or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db(‘database_name);

$rs = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table1, $dblink);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

$rowValue = $row['value'];

$explodeRowValue = (explode("||",$rowValue));

foreach ($explodeRowValue as $value_name) {
  $data[] = array(
            'key' => $value_name,
            'value' => $value_name
        );
}
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

So, what do you guys think? It's driving me crazy!

Sar

Comment: Your code has the error in  `mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table1, $dblink);` dont have the closing quota.

Comment: Your `DISTINCT` query should work just fine (`SELECT *` wouldn't even if you specified `DISTINCT` - you'd get a "random" id, not a stable result).  Probably, there is something different about the strings, likely whitespace (as Aziz's answer implies), but possibly some sort of encoding issue.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Whitespace isn't the problem in this case. I'll continue racking my brains tonight.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ Thanks! Didn't see that..but that isn't the solution :(  It still doesn't work which confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(value) FROM table1
```

Comment: I tried it the TRIM returns blank values! So that's not the solution. Thx for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table1", $dblink);
```

Comment: Given that his code shouldn't run _at all_ without the closing `'`, I doubt this will solve the problem.

Comment: @user1844933 Thanks for catching that...but that wasn't the problem. It's still spitting out the duplicates!

Comment: what is table name? if your tbl name column1 then try "SELECT DISTINCT value FROM column1"